# How to take emulator screenshots for coco2dx game

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, cocos2d-x, screenshot

I had developed a game in cocos2dX both for android and ios.

Now I want to take screenshot of the application for uploading to play store.

For this I need to capture screenshots from different android emulators. But when I took screenshots of the emulator while running the game using the capture button in eclipse i got black screen only.

I searched for the solution and found that its because I have enabled the use host GPU emulation in the AVD settings. But I enabled this for running cocos2dx game in the emulator. If I unchecked this option my game will crash in the emulator.

I have tried with api level 17 to 20 with this option checked and unchecked. But either the game will crash or the screenshot will be black screens. Can anyone suggest a solution o this problem. I have also tried many other suggestions like unchecking wipe user data etc.. from stack overflow and other forums. But could not find any perfect solution to work around this problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with API 15 and Intel x68 image. I use this with HAXM and I'm able to make screenshot with host GPU enabled

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use an external tool to capture the emulator's screen. E.g. a standard Windows accessory is the "Snipping Tool".

This works even with an emulator that has "Use Host CPU" enabled. It does lack some features like framing the screen shot to look like a phone with screen glare and a shadow.